# Как изменить цвет стрелки, нарисованной в Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, visual-basic

Как изменить цвет стрелки, нарисованной в Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Если подразумевается `Вставка -> Фигуры -> Стрелка вправо` (для примера):

```
' Обращаемся к массиву всех фигур на странице и выбираем нужную
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Right Arrow 1")).Select
With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    ' Здесь задается нужная цветовая схема
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent5
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
```

Либо использовать пошагово запись макросов и смотреть что меняется.

Answer (score 0):

В Excel есть замечательная справка, с множеством примеров.
Другой хороший способ - запись макросов. Начинаешь запись макроса, сам руками выполняешь нужные действия, которые должна будет выполнять программа, сохраняешь макрос и идешь смотреть в его код, какие методы и какие свойства используются.